# "The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage" in view with custom helper using standard helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, helper, inference

I've got some forms for an MVC3 website with alot of repeating parts. So I tried to make a helper for this. Following an example form the internet i made this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Nop.Web.Themes.MyTheme.Extensions
{
    public static class FormLineHelper
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString FormLine<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                                                                    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty[]>> expression,
                                                                    object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("tr");
            tag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);
            var member = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
            string propertyName = member.Member.Name;

            tag.InnerHtml += String.Format("<td class='label'>{0}</label></td><td class='field'>{1}</td><td class='padding'>{2}</td>",
               htmlHelper.LabelFor(expression), htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression), htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression));

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles just fine. However when i do

```
@model Nop.Plugin.MyPlugin.Models.ViewModel

@{
    Layout = "../Shared/_Root.cshtml";
}

<div class="form">
<div class="form-top"></div>
<div class="form-center">

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table>
    @Html.FormLine(model => model.FirstName)
   </table>
}
</div>
<div class="form-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I made sure the web.config contains

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

I get the "The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage" error. Another helper that works similair, but doesn't use the standard helpers works fine. I have also tried this:

```
@{ Html.FormLine<ViewModel, string>(model => model.FirstName); }
```

Which gives the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'".

I have seen similair questions but I haven't been able to find an answer. So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you get the array of properties?

How change this line:

```
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty[]>> expression,
```

With

```
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
```

Comment: Ah damn that is a sneaky little error. I completely read over that. I stare myself blind on these things. That works indeed using `@(Html.FormLine<ViewModel, string>(model => model.FirstName))`
Thanks!

Comment: And ofcourse now it also works like this: `@Html.FormLine(model => model.FirstName)`